# How can I get autocompletion for pdf.js in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I did the following:

```
npm init -y
npm install pdfjs-dist
```

Then I created a JavaScript file `test.js` in Visual Studio Code which contains:

```
const pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js");

const pdfPath = "test.pdf";
const doc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfPath).promise;
```

I would have expected auto completion e.g. when typing `await pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfPath).` but there wasn't. Is that the expected behaviour? Otherwise, how to enable autocompletion for such things?

Comment: what's the reason for importing `pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js` instead of `pdfjs-dist`? (I'm not familiar with the library)

Comment: I have no idea. However, after using import instead of require the autocompletion started working I think.